# Understand NSZombie message

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I enabled the nszombie in xcode 4.2. (from product->editScheme)

I have got this message:

```
-[buttons respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x48ae50
```

I do have buttons class, but i dont see what the exact problem by this message.

can i get more from the NSZombie ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this specific message means is that the `buttons` instance (at `0x48ae50`) has been deallocated (a.k.a. `release`d). So, by trying to send the `respondsToSelector:` message to `nothing` (remember the instance has been de-alloc'd), it throws an error.

Try setting a breakpoint near the place where it's being triggered and see why... (for now, your `buttons` object will most like have an address of `0x0`)

In most (if not all) cases, this has to do with some faulty memory management; an object being released too soon, not retained when it had to, etc... ;-)

Comment: i know its something that released with no reason, but this number 0x48ae50, does not mean anything to anyone. way xcode does not have any tool to just direct me to the specific object without a mess. am i asking for something that is not basic thing ??

Comment: @user1280535 Well, if you happen to have more than 1 instance of `buttons` and you really do not know which one that obscure `0x48ae50` address refers to, I'm with you; I don't know the answer to that myself and I'd be really happy if someone knew... :-)

Comment: thanks. even with instruments, after 1 year of development, i cant put my finger on the specific allocated object to solve problems. i am really looking for a new way to handle it.

Comment: @user1280535 I've been coding for like 18 years (just 1-2 with Objective-C and Cocoa though) and I still am not 100% sure how to solve memory-related issues, too. So, don't worry. Join the club! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that an object of type **buttons** was deallocated and then it's **respondsToSelector:** method was called, that object is at address 0x48ae50.

If you were running without NSZombies your application would have crashed.

Comment: it actually crash with zombie, exactly the moment that i get that message :)

Comment: Do you have a lot of buttons?

Comment: Pay attention to them, and note their address, when you see that message you know the one that's being over released, then find out why!